# Multiple redirect of the same URL in Apache HTTP server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using Apache HTTP server and have a url http://example.org. I want that any request that comes on this url should be redirected to http://example.org/init.html. This runs a script which evaluates the url and creates cookie. Then the url should come back on the server and be redirected to another url.

I am using

```
ProxyPass / /init.html
ProxyPassReverse / /init.html
```

After the response is back on the server then it should be redirected to another URL http://example2.com/. for the user, the browser url should still remain as http://example.com

Comment: The second redirect needs to be handled in your script.

Comment: No, It needs to be back on the server for authentication